# Is it possible to get an Activity object from other apps?

Tags: android, android-activity

I need to get the Activity from all the other installed apps on the device, possibly the launcher activity, but all of them is ok too. I know this code:

```
Intent launchIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.testapp.test");
```

that gives me an Intent object, but is there an equivalent to get an Activity object? Or some other method?
I've seen many topics similar to this one, but all of them return only the Activity name, the Intent, or a Context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but is there an equivalent to get an Activity object?

No. Those other apps are in other processes. While *those* processes may have `Activity` instances, you cannot access them, because those instances are not in *your* process.

Comment: Ok thanks to everyone, I'll just accept the first that answered.

Answer (score 1):

No.You cannot access Activity instance into other apps.Because both apps considered to be a separate process

Answer (score 1):

you cannot access the context of activity of another apps but if you want to take some result and post some data to other apps then with help of Intent you can do that and get result in onActivityResult() of your activity,s context.